# Why there is no booster parameter in the XGBoost installation, meanwhile it is in the documentation?

Tags: python, machine-learning, xgboost

I have installed the XGBoost.
These are the parameters it displays when doing:
    print(xgboost.XGBClassifier())

```
XGBClassifier(base_score=0.5, colsample_bylevel=1, colsample_bytree=1,
   gamma=0, learning_rate=0.1, max_delta_step=0, max_depth=3,
   min_child_weight=1, missing=None, n_estimators=100, nthread=-1,
   objective='binary:logistic', reg_alpha=0, reg_lambda=1,
   scale_pos_weight=1, seed=0, silent=True, subsample=1)
```

But in the documentation [Scikit-Learn API](http://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html#module-xgboost.sklearn), a "booster" parameter" appears. Why I do not have it?

```
Scikit-Learn API
Scikit-Learn Wrapper interface for XGBoost.

class xgboost.XGBRegressor(max_depth=3, learning_rate=0.1,  
n_estimators=100, silent=True, objective='reg:linear', 
**booster='gbtree'**, nthread=-1, gamma=0, min_child_weight=1, 
max_delta_step=0, subsample=1, colsample_bytree=1, colsample_bylevel=1, 
reg_alpha=0, reg_lambda=1, scale_pos_weight=1, base_score=0.5, seed=0, 
missing=None)
```

EDIT

This is what I get:

```
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-63-26499cfcb8f8> in <module>()
     18         #Inicio de Cross-validation
     19         clf = Pipeline([('rcl', RobustScaler()),
---> 20                         ('clf',    xgboost.XGBClassifier(booster='gbtree', objective='multi:softmax', seed=0,  nthread=-1))])
     21         ##############4 epoch x sujeto###########
     22         print("4 epoch x sujeto en test_size")

 TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'booster'
```

Answer (score 0):

IMHO that's a bad inconsistency you should open an issue for.

But the XGB python classes are more or less designed around the fact that you can set parameters in a bag through the `train` method.

So there you can actually supply the booster method via:

```
clf = xgb.XGBClassifier()
params = {"booster" : "gbtree"}
xgb.train(params, ...)
```

Comment: Well, if I add the parameter I get this error: TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'booster'. Any ideas?

Comment: @Aizzaac can you add the stacktrace please? Hard to follow the code for me otherwise.

Comment: I added it on EDIT.

Comment: According to the signature  it is missing : args=['self', 'max_depth', 'learning_rate', 'n_estimators', 'silent', 'objective', 'nthread', 'gamma', 'min_child_weight', 'max_delta_step', 'subsample', 'colsample_bytree', 'colsample_bylevel', 'reg_alpha', 'reg_lambda', 'scale_pos_weight', 'base_score', 'seed', 'missing'], varargs=None, keywords=None, defaults=(3, 0.1, 100, True, 'reg:linear', -1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0.5, 0, None))      Possibly (in my case) because I am using a wrapper, and didn't compiled from source